# Como recorro una lista?

Tags: java, poo, lista, arraylist, jframe

Como recorro una lista? como recorro los datos de ella como tal a una ventana Jframe llamada compras ... desde un control yo cargo una lista en un Jframe pero quisiera saber como recorrerla con que código se hace?

Comment: Paola , por favor añadir el código que se intentó hasta ahora.

Comment: Como te he comentado en tu pregunta más reciente, tomate el tiempo de (volver a?) hacer el recorrido del sitio. Alla aprendes como hacer buenas preguntas, las informaciónes que se esperan y como aceptar la respuesta que te soluciona tu inquietud y como votar para respuestas que te parecen útiles. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Java provee `.iterator()` para recibir un `Iterator` para recorrer la lista o usas ´for (int i = 0; i<=list.size();i++){ ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde Java 8 tienes 3 formas de recorrer una lista

-Utilizando un for
-Utilizando for-each
-Utilizando programacion funcional

veamos unos ejemplos :

```
//declaramos nuestra lista utilizando la interfaz List e indicamos que contendra objetos del tipo String
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

//for each : debemos indicar el dato que almacena la lista , en este caso String , luego debemos declarar una variable pivote (str) finalmente dos puntos (:) y la lista que vamos a recorrer
for(String str : lista)
{
    //imprimimos el objeto pivote
    System.out.println(str);
}

//for indicamos la variable indice en 0 para recorrer toda la lista, de inicio a fin al final de cada iteracion el indice se incrementa en uno
for(int indice = 0;indice<lista.size();indice++)
{
    System.out.println(lista.get(indice));
}

//utilizar el metodo foreach() de las colecciones de java , debemos llamar al metodo foreach de la instancia de coleccion y enviar un parametro del tipo Consumer
lista.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para reccorer un arrayList o un list con un for each se hace.

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
for(String cadena : array){
  System.out.println(cadena);
}
```

Donde el primer parametro del foreach es El tipo de dato, el segundo la variable temporal,  el tercero tu lista.

También se puede con un for normal

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i < array.size(); i++){
  System.out.println(array.get(i));
}
```

Comment: `foreach` no existe en `Java` es simplemente un `for`

Comment: @Dev.Joel Tienes razón, la palabra reservada como tal no existe como tal, confusión de lenguaje, edito, gracias por la corrección